# How to fetch nested objects all at once using restFb?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So I can fetch a post using this code:

```
Post post = facebookClient.fetchObject("postId", Post.class,  Parameter.with("id", "message","from"));
```

The "from" field returns the Author's id and name, **but not as an User object.**

To obtain the User Object I have to send a request again:

```
 User user = facebookClient.fetchObject(post.getFrom().getId, User.class, ..);
```

This can lead to an insane amount of request calls.

Am I able to fetch them at once?
like this:

```
MyPost extends Post{
    User fetchedUserWithFromFieldId;
}
```

and somehow invoke:

```
facebookClient.fetchObject("postId", MyPost.class,  Parameter.with("id", "message","from")).deepFetch("fetchedUserWithFromFieldId",User.class, Parameter.with("link","name","location"..etc));
```

So basically I need the FB equivalent of SQL's join.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

The parameter fields themselves can be nested.
**source:** https://restfb.com/documentation/  , **Chapter:** 'Request with fields (third to n-th level)'

```
facebookClient.fetchObject("postId", MyPost.class,  Parameter.with("id", "message","from{link,name,location}"));

MyPost extends Post{
    MyUser user; // MyUser has fields link,name,location.
}
```